# Determine Latitude and Longitude without a GPS

Tags: measurements

Is it possible to measure the strength of a rare earth magnet to determine latitude and longitude of a current position? For instance say you start with your known latitude and longitude and then use a compass, accelerometer or other sensor besides a GPS to get your coordinates. What sensors would make the most sense? What equations would you use to keep track of your location based upon a fixed point in space?

Comment: do you get to use detailed topographical maps? or are we talking flat ground?  This question might get better answers in GIS stack exchange.

Comment: The condition of "start with your known latitude and longitude" makes me think that the questioner actually wants to know about [inertial navigation systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system), though I'm not entirely sure where "measuring the strength of a rare earth magnet" comes into it. I too think that another stack exchange would be more suitable -- if not GIS, then aviation, physics, or space.

Comment: There are lots of questions here. Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking". Brian, perhaps you could narrow it down to one clear question?